# Python command in bash does not find -c flag

Tags: command-line, bash, python, scripts

I have two python lines in my bash script, both should run with **-c** flag, but once I run the Bash script it tells me that it could not find **-c** flag that is needed for python to run the command in Bash. It does work from command like if I copy the python command to command line it runs the command, but not from inside the script.

Error output:

```
mount.sh: 40: mount.sh: -c: not found
```

My script:

```
## define a function that launched the zenity username dialog
get_username(){
    zenity --entry --width=300 --title="Mount $MOUNTDIR" --text="Username:"
}
# define a function that launched the zenity password dialog
get_password(){
    zenity --entry --width=300 --title="Mount $MOUNTDIR" --text="Password:" --hide-text
}

# attempt to get the username and exit if cancel was pressed.
wUsername=$(get_username) || exit

# if the username is empty or matches only whitespace.
while [ "$(expr match "$wUsername" '.')" -lt "1" ]; do
    zenity --error --title="Error in username!" --text="Please check your username! Username field can not be empty!"  || exit
    wUsername=$(get_username) || exit
done

wPassword=$(get_password) || exit

while [ "$(expr match "$wPassword" '.')" -lt "1" ]; do
    zenity --error --title="Error in password!" --text="Please check your password! Password field can not be empty!" || exit
    wPassword=$(get_password) || exit
done

python -c 'import keyring; keyring.set_password("WinMount", wUsername, wPassword)'

Get_wPassword=python -c 'import keyring; keyring.get_password("WinMount", wUsername)'

# mount windows share to mountpoint
sudo mount -t cifs //$SERVER/$SHARE ${HOME}/${DIRNAME} -o username=${wUsername},password=$Get_wPassword,domain=${DOMAIN}
```

Comment: Whats your shebang line in the script? `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: Yes its #!/bin/bash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Get_wPassword=python -c 'import keyring; keyring.get_password("WinMount", wUsername)'
```

should probably be

```
Get_wPassword=$(python -c 'import keyring; keyring.get_password("WinMount", wUsername)')
```

and if you want `wUsername` to be given by the shell variable with the same name

```
Get_wPassword=$(python -c "import keyring; keyring.get_password('WinMount', '$wUsername')")
```

(note how the double quotes became single and vice versa)

Comment: This works thanks :) But how can I make python to take the wUsername from the bash, because it says its undefined at the moment, but I do write it in the zenity and I want it to take it from the zenity line after its inserted.

Comment: See my edit....

Comment: I have tried the way you edited it. It did not work. It says its undefined. See chaos post to right answer.

Comment: Ah sorry, you need to put quotes around `$wUsername` too, of course. Using `os.getenv` for that is way overkill, but whatever...

Comment: Your solution works as well. Because you have less rep I made your's the answer

Answer (score 4):

It's because of that line:

```
Get_wPassword=python -c 'import keyring; keyring.get_password("WinMount", wUsername)'
```

`-c` is interpreted as a command. Write it as follows:

```
Get_wPassword=$(python -c 'import keyring; keyring.get_password("WinMount", wUsername)')
```

**EDIT:** For the problem with the bash variable. You can use `os.getenv` to access environment variables from Python:

```
export wUsername
export wPassword
Get_wPassword=$(python -c "import keyring; import os; \
keyring.get_password("WinMount", os.getenv('wUsername'))")
unset wPassword
```

Comment: +1 for os.getenv, this will work even if 'wUsername' has quotes in it.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
Get_wPassword=python -c 'import keyring; keyring.get_password("WinMount", wUsername)'
```

means "Run `-c` with $Get_wPassword set to `python`"

To just set `$Get_wPassword` to the the whole command use

```
Get_wPassword='python -c \'import keyring; keyring.get_password("WinMount", wUsername)\''
```